# Visual and Logical tree traversal does not retrieve several levels

Tags: c#, wpf, visualtreehelper, logical-tree

I'm exploring logical and visual trees from the same application without success going deeper through the levels.

My code uses a generic explorer:

```
private static void ProcessGenericTree(object current, List<FrameworkElement> leaves, Type treeType) 
        {
            if (current is FrameworkElement)
            {
                if (!leaves.Contains(current as FrameworkElement))
                    leaves.Add(current as FrameworkElement);
            }

            DependencyObject dependencyObject = current as DependencyObject;

            if (dependencyObject != null)
            {
                if (treeType.Equals(typeof(VisualTreeHelper)))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); i++)
                    {
                        ProcessVisualTree(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i), leaves);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (object child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(dependencyObject))
                    {
                        ProcessLogicalTree(child, leaves);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

`ProcessLogicalTree` and `ProcessVisualTree` simply iterate (doing something before the `ProcessGenericTree` re-call).

The result looks complete, but when I'm trying to retrieve a `TextBlock` into a `GridViewColumn` Header it looks like the item doesn't exist neither in the Logical nor in the Visual leaves list of `FrameworkElement`.

It seems to be a **Visual Element** into a **Logical Element**. In fact adding a watch this `TextBlock` appears in the **Visual Children** of my `GridView` (retrieved as logical, it stands in a `Tab Item` not selected), but my code isn't unable to get it.

My call is pretty simple:

```
         ProcessVisualTree(root, _visualElements);
         ProcessLogicalTree(root, _logicalElements);
```

where root is the MainWindow.

So, how can I explore my tree at its deepest level? Maybe re-iterating through the retrieved `FrameworkElement` list? I think my ProcessGeneric code already does it.

**Update**: the WPF Visualizer shows a structure of this kind:

```
ListView > ScrollViewer > Grid > DockPanel > Grid > ScrollContentPresenter > GridViewHeaderRowPresenter > GridViewColumnHeader > HeaderBorder
```

The `GridViewColumnHeader` level contains my `TextBlock` but the visual tree doesn't.

**Update 2**: using the recursion starting from the main window with my element visible I'm not able to Find the object with a specified name with this code:

```
public static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                return (T)child;
            }

            T childItem = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childItem != null) return childItem;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm pretty sure the `VisualTreeHelper` is not able to retrieve elements inside Header property but the [WPF Inspector](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/) works correctly.

I wonder if it uses a different approach to traverse the tree (maybe inspecting the `Properties` like `Header` too). Suggestions?

Comment: I wonder if this is because the `Header` property is not a `DependencyObject` its is of type `object` so the `Header` itself won't jet picked up in your iteration therefore anything inside won't either, Just a hunch, perhaps you could test this by assigning a `FrameWorkElement` to the `Tag` property and see if that gets picked up in your loop. But like I said its just a guess :)

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I'll try, now using http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/ I'm able to see the entire structure.